# C++/Win32 Smallest possible MessageBox("Hello") app exe?

Tags: c++, winapi, optimization

I am working on a project that is getting really large and I need to have the exe uploaded to someone every time a new build is out, and my connection is by phone modem.

I want to compile the smallest possible exe for an application whose purpose is to run the code: `MessageBox(0, "Hello", 0, MB_OK);`

I am using Visual Studio 2010. My attempts so far:

Version 0, size and switches:

> 7kB (release)
>   Used: \O1

Version 1, size and switches:

> 3kB (release)
>   Used: \O1, Off buffer security check, Ignore default library linkage.

Can this be made even smaller than 3kB? What compiler flags influence the size of the executable?

Comment: Probably about compiler flags.

Comment: What compiler flags should I use? what headers to include? what VC project settings? other program that can compress exe size?

Comment: Starting Message Box from console will produce the smallest application.

Comment: You can get down to 268 bytes if size is really an issue, but you'll ahve to forfeit VC++ and get your hands dirty with ASM. Here's an example of such 268 bytes file: https://www.codejuggle.dj/creating-the-smallest-possible-windows-executable-using-assembly-language/#comment-38 (still works on Win7, just tested).

Answer (score 9):

Link dynamically against the CRT (i.e. select "Multithreaded DLL" for the CRT in the code generation options; should be the default). Select size optimization. Tell the linker to lower the alignment requirement (/ALIGN and [/OPT:NOWIN98](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235956), can be entered in the command line options box under the linker options in the project config dialog) (note: this might result in your application not running under some Windows versions).

In addition to that you can use a packer, like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/), but keep in mind that some antivirus tools falsely detect packed executables as malware if they can't successfully analyze their content. Other available packers for Windows executables include [Crinkler](http://www.crinkler.net/) and [kkrunchy](http://www.farbrausch.de/~fg/kkrunchy/)

Even without a packer you can do some tricks, like merging PE sections and placing code inside the PE header. By doing this you could get a simple "Hello world" MessageBox executable in around 700 bytes or so (uncompressed). I don't think the Visual C++ linker supports these kind of operations though. See the [Tiny PE](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/) page for an example of how this can be done manually (he takes it to the extreme).

Comment: I think you need to put /MD to link against the dynamic library if compiling from the command line.

Comment: @JohnB: yeah that might be true. I only build stuff through the IDE when using Microsoft's compiler.

Comment: Link dynamically against the CRT? what is CRT? Select size optimization: Done. /ALIGN and /OPT:NOWIN98? where in VC 2010? which packer is best? how do I merge PE sections?

Comment: CRT == C(++)? RunTime.  Basically, the library that provides the standard API (and often some other stuff), and usually provides the function that sets stuff up and calls `main`.

Comment: so how do I link dynamically?

Comment: @user1581390: I've updated my answer with info about some of your additional questions.

Comment: A packer will likely *increase* the size, because it needs to embed its own unpacking code. Linking against the CRT is unnecessary. The code itself is just a few tens of bytes or so (or less, I didn't check), so it's absurd to try to pack it or place it anywhere non-standard. In short, there's a lot of misleading info in this answer. I do understand why people vote it up, though: this is SO.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new C++ Win32 Project, and select the empty project option.

Add a file, main.cpp, with the following contents:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void HelloWorldMain()
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Hello", 0, MB_OK);
}
```

In the project properties, turn off Buffer Security Check (C++ > Code Generation), Ignore All Default Libraries (Linker > Input), and set the Entry Point (Linker > Advanced) to HelloWorldMain.

Build the Release configuration; the output exe will be 3K.

Answer (score 3):

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

void startup()
{
    MessageBox( 0, L"Hello", L"Hi", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
    ExitProcess( 0 );
}
```

---

```
[d:\dev\test]
> cl foo.cpp kernel32.lib user32.lib /O2 /link /entry:startup /subsystem:windows
foo.cpp

[d:\dev\test]
> dir foo.exe
 Volume in drive D is data
 Volume Serial Number is A875-F9FD

 Directory of d:\dev\test

09.08.2012  18:00             2 560 foo.exe
               1 File(s)          2 560 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  144 102 051 840 bytes free

[d:\dev\test]
> _
```

Answer (score -3):

something like:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     MessageBox (NULL, "Hello, Windows 98!", "HelloMsg", MB_OK) ;

     return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: And there may also be a size reduction if you compile with the [/O1 flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx).

Comment: How do I set /O1 in VC 2010 project settings/properties?